# Dual of Quotient Space of a dual

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, quotient-spaces, duality-theorems, dual-spaces

Let $X$ be a nonreflexive banach space, $X^\ast$ its dual and $U$ some closed subset of $X$. Denote with $U^\perp$ the annihilator of $U$ given by
$$
 U^\perp = \{ x^\ast \in X^\ast \;|\; \forall x\in U: x^\ast(x)=0  \}
$$
I am interested in the dual of $X^\ast/U^\perp$. What is $(X^\ast/U^\perp)^\ast$?

#### My attempt:

It is known that
$$
(X/U)^\ast \cong U^\perp \\
X^\ast/U^\perp \cong U^\ast \\
U^\perp \subseteq X^\ast \\
U^\perp \text{ closed}
$$
Hence
$$
(X^\ast/U^\perp)^\ast = (U^\perp)^\perp
$$
Based on the defintion of the annihilator above
$$
(U^\perp)^\perp = \{ x^{\ast\ast} \in (X^\ast)^\ast \;|\; \forall x^\ast\in U^\perp: x^{\ast\ast}(x^\ast)=0  \}
$$
If $X$ was reflexive, then $(X^\ast)^\ast=X$ and this would mean that
$$
(U^\perp)^\perp = \{ x \in X \;|\; \forall x^\ast\in U^\perp: x^\ast(x)=0  \}
$$
If $X$ is not reflexive, like I have, then $(U^\perp)^\perp$ can also be written as
$$
(U^\perp)^\perp = \overline{span(U)}
$$
where $\overline{span(U)}$ is the weak$^\ast$ closed span of $U$.

Is this correct?

Sources:

- [Canonical isometric isomorphism.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257289/canonical-isometric-isomorphism)
- [Annihilator of an annihilator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2509811/annihilator-of-an-annihilator?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the result is correct.  However, I have some remarks:

First, the $\operatorname{span}$ is not needed, because
$U$ is already a subspace.
Some people denote the weak$*$-closure by $\overline{U}^{w*}$.

Second, your second source defines the annihilator in slightly different way:
With their definition, one would have $(U^\perp)^\perp \subset X$,
but with your definition it is $(U^\perp)^\perp \subset X^{**}$.